# JSONata prevent array flattening

Tags: jsonata

Q: How do I prevent JSONata from "auto-flattening" arrays in an array constructor?

Given JSON data:

```
{
  "w" : true,
  "x":["a", "b"],
  "y":[1, 2, 3],
  "z": 9
}
```

the JSONata query seems to select 4 values:

```
[$.w, $.x, $.y, $.z]
```

The nested arrays at $.x and $.y are getting flattened/inlined into my outer wrapper, resulting in more than 4 values:

```
[ true, "a", "b", 1, 2, 3, 9 ]
```

The results I would like to achieve are

```
[ true, ["a", "b"], [1, 2, 3], 9 ]
```

I can achieve this by using

```
[$.w, [$.x], [$.y], $.z]
```

But this requires me to know *a priori* that $.x and $.y are arrays.

I would like to select 4 values and have the resulting array contain exactly 4 values, independent of the types of values that are selected.

There are clearly some things about the interactions between JSONata sequences and arrays that I can't get my head around.

Comment: In my struggle to understand the behavior of array construction in JSONata I found [https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/93](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/93) to provide some useful context. In the spirit of providing constructive feedback, I want to let you know that I am having a great deal of difficulty understanding the model of array vs. XPath/XQuery-like-sequence behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In common with XPath/XQuery sequences, it will flatten the results of a path expression into the output array.  It is possible to avoid this in your example by using the `$each` higher-order function to iterate over an object's key/value pairs.  The following expression will get what you want without any flattening of results:

```
$each($, function($v) {
  $v
})
```

[This](http://try.jsonata.org/Hk5pIuGjz) just returns the value for each property in the object.

UPDATE: Extending this answer for your updated question:
I think this is related to a previous [github question](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/69#issuecomment-328100132) on how to combine several independent queries into the same question.  This uses an object to hold all the queries in a similar manner to the one you arrived at.  Perhaps a slightly clearer expression would be [this](http://try.jsonata.org/rkjZL87oG):

```
{
  "1":  t,
  "2": u.i,
  "3": u.j,
  "4": u.k,
  "5": u.l,
  "6": v
} ~> $each(λ($v){$v})
```

The `λ` is just a shorthand for `function`, if you can find it on your keyboard (F12 in the JSONata Exerciser).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. OK ... my simple example did not adequately demonstrate the problem. Your explanation shows me how to use $each if I want to iterate all of the values in the object. I actually don't want to select all items, but want to select n specific sub-trees and collect them into an array of length n. I will post a better example.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling to rephrase my question in such as way as to describe the difficulties I am having with JSONata's *sequence-like* treatment of arrays.

I need to run several queries to extract several values from the same JSON tree. I would like to construct one JSONata query expression which extracts *n* data items (or runs *n* subqueries) and returns exactly *n* values in an ordered array.

[This example](http://try.jsonata.org/BymDSZXof) seems to query request 6 values, but because of array flattening the result array does not have 6 values.

[This example](http://try.jsonata.org/BJ9671Qjz) explicitly wraps each query in an array constructor so that the result has 6 values. However, the values which are not arrays are wrapped in an extraneous & undesirable array. In addition one cannot determine what the original type was ...

[This example](http://try.jsonata.org/HykiS-7iG) shows the result that I am trying to accomplish ... I asked for 6 things and I got 6 values back. However, I must know the datatypes of the values I am fetching and explicitly wrap the arrays in an array constructor to work-around the sequence flattening.

[This example](http://try.jsonata.org/r1MbOG7iz) shows what I want. I queried 6 things and got back 6 answers without knowing the datatypes. But I have to introduce an object as a temporary container in order to work around the array flattening behavior.

I have not found any predicates that allow me to test the type of a value in a query ... which might have let me use the ?: operator to dynamically decide whether or not to wrap arrays in an array constructor. e.g. $isArray($.foo) ? [$.foo] : $.foo

Q: Is there an easier way for me to (effectively) submit 6 "path" queries and get back 6 values in an ordered array without knowing the data types of the values I am querying?

Answer (score 0):

Building on the example from Acoleman, here is a way to pass in `n` "query" strings (that represent paths):

```
(['t', 'u.i', 'u.j', 'u.k', 'u.l', 'v'] {
    $: $eval('$$.' & $)
}).$each(function($o) {$o})
```

and get back an array of`n` results with their original data format:

```
[
  12345,
  [
    "i",
    "ii",
    "iii"
  ],
  [],
  "K",
  {
    "L": "LL"
  },
  null
]
```

It seems that using `$each` is the only way to avoid any flattening...

Granted, probably not the most efficient of expressions, since each has to be evaluated from a path string starting at the root of the data structure -- but there ya go.